# Call SQL procedure from Workflow - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, sql

Is there a way to call an procedure stored on SQL server from SharePoint 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom activity for this

https://executespwf.codeplex.com/

Or

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/60840

Comment: thanks for the help. The first one from codeplex didnt even put documentation how to install it... baaad customer support